# PhantomJS is the library re-entrant?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I want to use phantom in order to create a pdf of a page in our client app, and the method will be called from within the client app. We use the phantom npm package and the following methods:

- phantom.create
- instance.createPage
- setCookies
- page.open
- page.render with a pdf format file

If we have concurrent calls (by multiple clients), is phantom able to use these methods within two separate instances or may the two instances collision with each other? 
Furthermore, will cookies be shared amongst the two separate instances?

Comment: What ? Issue ? How do one identify that ? __BAD Question__

Comment: From where? C or javascript?

Comment: PhantomJS uses asynchronous processing so you can have multiple requests at the same time. There are many types of requests which all have different issues. Please clarify what you're talking about.

Comment: @ArtjomB. : I just clarified the question

Comment: What *"instances"* are you talking about? Are you asking about `phantom` if you mention `phantom.create`? Also, you haven't mentioned this before, but it seems to me that you're not using PhantomJS directly, but rather a bridge to it from node.js. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is not large, have used Python master program, phantomjs as a tool for the request, you can achieve the operation of multi process, coupled with the redis queue can be more than the operation of the machine process. If the problem is that you have the resources to compete

Comment: Please reformulate

Comment: ok.Please consider so, sometimes I need is to allow the request with js processing capacity, then I will call this has been a good package of the code, the code in this link https://github.com/PyCN/ Anti-Anti-Spider / blob / master / phantomjs / get_page_Source_Code / request.js
Use the command is: phantomjs request.js http://www.google.com/ open a python process call this command, the return of the data can be a regular match

Comment: [link](https://github.com/PyCN/Anti-Anti-Spider/tree/master/phantomjs/get_page_Source_Code)